Creating a Symfony bundle - what should the config files in my bundle that configure other bundles look like?
I've created a simple admin system with login/logout and user CRUD functionality in Symfony.
I want to make this into a bundle so that I can re-use it in other applications.
I've now got it working as a standalone bundle, but my bundle depends on a couple of other bundles that need to be configured from within my bundle, which I'm doing with:
public function prependExtension(ContainerConfigurator $containerConfigurator, ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder): void
{
    // prepend config from a file
    $containerConfigurator->import('../config/packages/pagerfanta.yaml');
    $containerConfigurator->import('../config/packages/security.yaml');
    $containerConfigurator->import('../config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml');
    $containerConfigurator->import('../config/packages/twig.yaml');
}

I just copied these config files from my original Symfony project into my bundle and that works. But if someone installs my bundle, they will also get their own security.yaml file for their main project that looks like this:
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon

And the one in my bundle currently looks like this, so there's a lot of duplication here:
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ['ROLE_MANAGER']
        ROLE_MANAGER: ['ROLE_EMPLOYEE']

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: app_login

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    # access_control:
        # - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        # - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_EMPLOYEE }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon

My question is: should my bundle's security.yaml contain all of this duplicate config, or only the values that are different from the security.yaml file that Symfony installs for the main application? A user of my bundle might delete the main security.yaml file for their application or change values. What config do I need to keep to make sure my bundle keeps working?
